# Ruby rounding of variable

Tags: ruby, variables, rounding

Need help with the round method when using variables. I need to round the amount variable to 2 decimals.
Round method dosen't seem to work on variable, regardless if i change it to a float or not.

```
def amount
  amount = 0 
  amount = principal * (1 + rate / times_compounded) ** (times_compounded * years)
  p amount
  amount.to_f.round(2)
  p amount
  amount.round(2)
  p amount
```

Output

```
610.0950199739835
610.0950199739835
610.0950199739835
```

Comment: Your method `amount` needs an `end` and the variables `rate`, `times_compounded` and `years` have not been initialized (and are not arguments).  I suggest you delete the question, edit, test in IRB, then undelete. `(610.0950199739835).round(3) => 610.095` works just fine.

Comment: Ah, for a second I was worried I couldn't find the "cannot be reproduced / is a typographical error" close vote..

Comment: @Cary Swoveland , this is just the method, all variable have been initialized since the output is an actual number therefor values are being passed correctly. Whole method works except for the rounding. enrico.bacis solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving output of rounding the variable. Try this:

```
amount = 1.23456789
amount = amount.round(2)
puts amount                    # 1.23
```